# Size of a vector of pairs

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am filling up an adjacency list of vector with pairs given by :

```
vector<pair<int, int>> adj[1000];
```

I am doing a depth first search on the list but experiencing some weird behaviour. The first print statement prints some value which means I have some items in adj[s][0], adj[s][1], adj[s][2] and so on. However when I calculate the size of adj[s] in the next line it prints out to be zero. Am I missing something here?. Is my definition for vector of pairs correct?. The adjacency list is correctly filled because when I ran `cout << adj[s][0].first << endl;` in dfs, it was correctly showing me the neighbors of each and every node.

Complete code

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <climits>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

vector<pair<int, int>> adj[1000];
bool visited[1000];
int nodeweight[1000];

void initialize()
    {
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        visited[i] = false;
    for(int i=0; i < 1000; i++)
        adj[i].clear();
    for(int i = 0; i <1000; i++)
        nodeweight[i] = INT_MAX;
}

void dfs(int s)
    {
    visited[s] = true;
    cout << adj[s][1].first << endl;
    int minimum = INT_MAX, tovisit = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < adj[s].size(); i++)
        {
        cout << adj[s][i].second;
        if(!visited[adj[s][i].first] && adj[s][i].second < minimum)
            {
            minimum = adj[s][i].second;
            tovisit = adj[s][i].first;
        }
    }
    nodeweight[tovisit] = minimum;
    //dfs(tovisit);
}

int main() {
    int N, E;
    cin >> N >> E;

    while(E--)
        {
        int i, j, w;
        cin >> i >> j >> w;
        adj[i].push_back(make_pair(j,w));
        adj[j].push_back(make_pair(i,w));
    }

    initialize();

    for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
        {
        dfs(i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that you insert elements into `adj[][] `? Show us this part as well.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `vector<pair<int, int> > adj[1000];` with the space between the two `>`? I fear otherwise it would not even compile

Comment: It is compiling correctly. I have also added code to insert in adj list.

Comment: @PRP from C++11, compilers can recognize this new syntax.

Comment: Yes the adjacency list is correctly filled because when I ran cout << adj[s][0].first << endl; it was correctly showing me the neighbors of each and every node.

Comment: Check that you did insert a pair to the vector in position `s`. Seems like you are either sending the wrong index to the DFS or didn't insert correctly into that index.

Comment: @ShadKhan Instead of posting individual snippets. Post the full code here so that we can see the complete flow of your program.

Comment: I have added the complete code.

Comment: @ShadKhan If you had posted the complete code earlier, you might had got the answers in seconds:)

Comment: thanks. That was a stupid mistake :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are clearing `adj` again after filling in `initialize()`.

First you fill `adj` in the `while` loop in `main`. Then you call `initialize()` which includes this loop clearing all vectors in it:

```
for(int i=0; i < 1000; i++)
    adj[i].clear();
```

Then you have `cout << adj[s][1].first << endl;` in `dfs` which is undefined behavior because there are no elements in `adj[s]`. The fact that you seem to get the correct results is just coincidental undefined behavior (although practical it is because the memory holding the vector data was not cleared.)

`adj[s].size()` is correctly reported as `0`.